# equivalent ruby hash or array to a xml for soap call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to call a soap web service from zoyto. I have tried the following code which is not working for me  :-

```
def get_order_status
    require 'soap/wsdlDriver' 
    api_key = 'key value'
    api_secret = 'secret' 
    timestamp = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") 
    version = "2.0" 
    service_name = 'Zoyto Fulfillment Service' 
    method = 'getOrderStatus' 
    canonical_string = (service_name + method + timestamp).downcase 
    digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1') 
    signature = (Base64::encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, api_secret, canonical_string))).chomp
    clientorderids = [ "1"] 
    wsdlfile = "https://test.zoyto.com/zfulfillment/api/?WSDL" 
    service = "Zoyto Fulfillment" 
    digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
    XSD::Charset.encoding = 'UTF8' 
    driver = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdlfile).create_rpc_driver
    driver.wiredump_dev = $stdout
    response = driver.getOrderStatus({ :api_key => api_key, :timestamp => timestamp, :signature => signature, :version => version})
  end
```

and the input xml is like this-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getOrderStatus xmlns="http://zoyto.com/">
      <api_key>#{api_key}</api_key>
      <timestamp>#{timestamp}</timestamp>
      <signature>#{signature}</signature>
      <version>#{version}</version>
    </getOrderStatus>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

what is the equivalent hash to the above xml to pass in the web service.